# PostgreSQL ORDER BY clause on numerical portion of text column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table that has a column as primary key and the values are

```
G1,G2,G3,...Gn
```

I would like to order the data but the problem is when I use the `ORDER BY` clause it displays data as:

```
G1,G10,G11... G2,G20,G21, ... G3,G30,G31....
```

The query I use is:

```
select * from myTable order by id asc;
```

Comment: @Glorfindel Not a duplicate of the question you mention, even though a solution is there. That question is about creating a new PK for a column with alpha and numerical characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` column is obviously of some text data type so the ordering is alphabetical, not by the number. To get it to work, strip the 'G' from the `id` column when ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
ORDER BY right(id, -1)::integer;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! That worked